# Python working with data table with keys and values in another table?

Tags: python, pandas, key

I am currently working with data that has over 20 variables (columns) in the main data table, however the column for example weather conditions has a key 1 or 2, or 3 etc. and there is another table for lookups with the values of the keys. Each variable with a key has its own table with the value of the key. In excel I would use vlookups and replace the keys with the values, what is the method called where you can work with the indexes and at the end interpret them with the values?

Thanks

Comment: Probably want to learn pandas.  pd.merge() might be what you're looking for.

Comment: you can use pandas merge or joins. But to get a clear answer an example would be great.

Comment: The data is on accidents which have several features, weather, road conditions, gender, age category, all the features are category data and keys are stored in the main data set and values in a separate file e.g. 1 = sunny. @Avind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your look-up table to a dictionary, and then use Pandas' [replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method to convert all the keys in your main dataframe to the longer descriptions that are located in your look-up table.

Here's an example:

Say you have a dataframe called `df` that has a `Weather` column like this:

```
    Weather
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   3
4   2
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   2
9   3
```

And then say your look-up table is called `keys_df` and looks like this:

```
    Key Meaning
0   1   Sunny
1   2   Cloudy
2   3   Rainy
```

First follow these two steps to convert your look-up table `keys_df` to a dictionary:

1. Set the `Key` column as the index using Pandas' [set_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) method:

   `keys_df = keys_df.set_index('Key')`
2. Then use Pandas' [to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method to create a dictionary from the `keys_df` lookup table:

   `key_dict = keys_df.to_dict()`

At this point the look-up dictionary will look like this:

`{'Meaning': {1: 'Sunny', 2: 'Cloudy', 3: 'Rainy'}}`

The final step is to use the [replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method to replace each number in the `Weather` column in your main dataframe `df` with its text description, which are contained in a dictionary under the `Meaning` key inside the dictionary returned by the `to_dict()` method:

`df.loc[:,'Weather'] = df['Weather'].replace(key_dict['Meaning'])`

This will make your `Weather` column look like this:

```
    Weather
0   Sunny
1   Cloudy
2   Rainy
3   Rainy
4   Cloudy
5   Sunny
6   Sunny
7   Sunny
8   Cloudy
9   Rainy
```

Comment: Thanks james that's what I was looking for, I forgot the technical term for the lookup table was a reference table.